# How can I specify dependency minimum and maximum version in setup.cfg?

Tags: python, dependencies, python-packaging, requirements

### Problem description

I would want to define the install requirement for my pip package. Let's say FooLibrary's version should be >=2 but <3.2.

Currently, I have

```
[options]
install_requires =
    FooLibrary >= 2
```

### Question

How can I add a rule for maximum version of the library together with the minimum version rule?

Answer (score 2):

Separate version requirements with commas.

So for example, in this case, `FooLibrary >=2,<3.2` works